# How can i remove the commas between words and make them go under each subheading

Tags: python

my python code so far is:

```
list=("Member ID, Surname, Year joined, Nights booked, Membership status, Points balance")
f = open("SampleData2017.txt")
print(list)
for surname in f.readlines():
   print(surname)
```

however when i run it the items are only seperated by commas and not under each subheading

i want it to look like:

```
MemberID  Surname  Year  joined Membershipstatus  Nightsbooked  Points balance
Gri33415 Griffiths    2015         Gold               35          40000

Smi22316  Smith       2016        Silver              3            7500
```

how would i fix this? as simple as possible please

Comment: Can you please show exactly how you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Please edit your question and put your expectation in the question, not the comments.

Comment: i made it more specific if that helps

Comment: `list` is a bad name for a variable because you overwrite the builtin [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). In this case it's even worse and leads to false assumptions, because what you call a list is in fact a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use python built in csv module to achieve what you want

Edit 1:

Observe headers is assigned initially as string and then converted list

added ljust to each items to give an idea how this can be achieved, but definitely not the exact alignment the way you want.

```
import csv
headers="Member ID, Surname, Year joined, Nights booked, Membership status, Points balance"
headers = headers.split(',')

print ('\t'.join(x.ljust(5) for x in headers))

with open('WorkingDirectory\stars.csv', 'r') as mycsv:
    rows = csv.reader(mycsv)
    for row in rows:
        print ('\t'.join(x.ljust(15) for x in row))
```

Original Answer:

```
import csv

headers=["Member ID, Surname, Year joined, Nights booked, Membership status, Points balance"]

print ('\t'.join(headers))

with open('SampleData2017.txt', 'r') as mycsv:
    rows = csv.reader(mycsv)
    for row in rows:
        print ('\t'.join(row))
```

Output:

```
Member ID, Surname, Year joined, Nights booked, Membership status, Points balance
Gri33415    Griffiths   2015    Gold    35  40000
Smi22316    Smith   2016    Silver  3   7500
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but is there any way that they may align better under each heading?

Comment: Answer Updated but may not be perfect for your use case. but you can tweak a little if it is suitable. 

Else you need to assign length for each columns and do `ljust` for each element based on your header length f each names. Let me know if you need any assistance here

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a list of headers, and a table full of data you're pulling from `SampleData2017.txt`. There's a third-party module called `tabulate` that I use a lot for this because it keeps me from having to write a bunch of code for a simple task.

Install it from pypi using pip on your command line.

```
$ pip install tabulate
```

or on Python3

```
$ pip3 install tabulate
```

Then write code:

```
import tabulate

headers = map(str.strip, "Member ID, Surname, Year joined, Nights booked, Membership status, Points balance".split(","))
# or just format it yourself:
headers = ("Member ID", "Surname", "Year joined", "Nights booked",
           "Membership status", "Points balance")

with open("SampleData2017.txt") as f:
    # you never say how each row is split into fields, so I'm assuming here
    # that it's comma-separated and calling str.split(",") on each
    table = tabulate.tabulate((line.split(",") for line in f), headers=headers)
```

With my sample data here, the output is:

```
>>> headers = ("one", "two", "three")
>>> data = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]

>>> print(tabulate.tabulate(data, headers=headers))
  one    two    three
-----  -----  -------
    1      2        3
    4      5        6
    7      8        9
```